# Citrix and firefox in ubuntu 12.04 window disappears too fast!

Tags: 12.04, citrix

Running 12.04 and got citrix receiver installed OK (I think) but when I go to launch an .ica and I have set firefox to use wfica to handle these files, a window pops up and then disappears super fast... I cant see what it says or what is going on.  Any ideas? Can I run something in terminal to give me info on what occurs?

Thanks